# What is end-to-end in Computer Networking?

Tags: internet

I'm very new in computer networking. I'm reading `Computer Networking  A Top-Down Approach (KUROSE, ROSS)` book.

In the beginning of chapter one, it said :

> We'll take the broader and more abstract view in the second half of
>   this chapter.  We'll examine delay, loss and throughput of data in a
>   computer network and provide simple quantitative models for **end-to-end**
>   throughput and delay: models that take  into account transmission,
>   propagation, and queuing delays.

I'm confusing in peace that said `end-to-end`. I don't know what it is!

Please explain to me what is `end-to-end` briefly ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i know reason of downvote?

Comment: Often, if your question can be answered by a few seconds of Googling -- e.g. [end-to-end principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle) -- people will down vote. (It was not me who down-voted.)

Comment: I work in IT, have for years, and wouldn't have known to look for "end-to-end principle" which sounds like marketing FUD... but then, maybe it sounds that way due to having worked in IT for years...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means from point A to point B in the network and everything in between (in this context)

ex:

PC (A)=> switch => router => router => switch => PC (B)

Answer (score 2):

end to end is a common term used in the context of network performance, qos, security and network management. consider as well the endpoint is often a server however now includes video and voip phones, wireless and any device with TCP/IP connectivity. so the question gets more complex as well when considering network latency and what is end to end. is it to the primary web server or to the backend cloud database servers ?

Comment: Agreed, there are assumptions made at many levels on what end is going to what other end. To me as a data plumber, it's IP to IP and port. To the poor schlub who's responsible for the web app, it's also all those back end connections (which are, to me, DIFFERENT end-to-end connections).

Comment: Frankly, this is very clear from a network viewpoint. If a client is talking to a web server, the end to end is the client to web server. It doesn't matter how many connections the web server makes to other resources to provide the requested service. When you start dragging in backend connections, you move from worrying about network performance to application performance, which is an entirely separate issue.